# Using Import time within your Url

Tags: python, python-import

This is the first attempt at using `import time` with a python script. Within the `URL` I am trying to replace the static date with a dynamic date. The date in the `URL` is in this format `12-21-2017`. Is that possible with `import time`?

```
import csv
import requests
import time


outfile = open("Labs_StartingGoalies.csv","w",newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerow(["HomeTeam","HomeGoalie","HomeGoalieStatus","DK","FD","VisitorTeam","VisitorGoalie","VisitorGoalieStatus","DK","FD"])

req = requests.get('https://www.fantasylabs.com/api/lines/4/' + %M-%d-%Y + '/startinggoalies') 
data = req.json()['GoalieMatchups']

for teams in data:
    HomeTeam = teams['Properties']['HomeTeam']
    HomeGoalie = teams['Properties']['HomeGoalie']
    HomeGoalieStatus = teams['Properties']['HomeGoalieStatus']
    HomeGoalieSalary_DK = teams['Properties']['HomeGoalieSalary_DK']
    HomeGoalieSalary_FD = teams['Properties']['HomeGoalieSalary_FD']

    VisitorTeam = teams['Properties']['VisitorTeam']
    VisitorGoalie = teams['Properties']['VisitorGoalie']
    VisitorGoalieStatus = teams['Properties']['VisitorGoalieStatus']
    VisitorGoalieSalary_DK = teams['Properties']['VisitorGoalieSalary_DK']
    VisitorGoalieSalary_FD = teams['Properties']['VisitorGoalieSalary_FD']


    writer.writerow([HomeTeam,HomeGoalie,HomeGoalieStatus,HomeGoalieSalary_DK,HomeGoalieSalary_FD,VisitorTeam,VisitorGoalie,VisitorGoalieStatus,VisitorGoalieSalary_DK,VisitorGoalieSalary_FD])
outfile.close()
```

Comment: Use datetime: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module which supersedes `time`.

On its own, `%M-%d-%Y` is meaningless. It's a format string that should be passed to the module, but you haven't actually defined it as a string, let alone passed it to the `time` module.

Change:
`%M-%d-%Y`

To:

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

NOTE:
`%M` is for *minutes*, not month. You need to change it to lowercase "m".

Comment: `www.fantasylabs.com/api/lines/4/' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%M-%d-%Y') + '/startinggoalies')`. Like So?

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson that should work (you would have to `import datetime` somewhere) but I'm also trying to look up URL formatting to see if there might be a better way overall.

Comment: After making that edit and `Import datetime` it will now give me an error on line `data = req.json()['GoalieMatchups']` No data writes to the `CSV`.

Comment: Thank you, that will help a lot!